# How to Rotation.from_euler with different value in Axis data

Tags: python, math, scipy, rotation, mesh

I have these data for the rotation of a mesh:
`<axis>0 0 1</axis> <angle>3.141592502593994</angle>`

I would like to use the function with python from scipy : "Rotation.from_euler(axis, angle)"
I understand that "axis" take "x","y","z" as argument, in this case it quite easy, if the data is equal to 1, I simply
`Rotation.from_euler("z", angle)`

But sometime, I have these cases :

`<axis>-0.5773503184318542 -0.5773501396179199 -0.5773503184318542</axis> <angle>2.0943949222564697</angle>`

`<axis>0.7071067690849304 -0.7071067690849304 0</axis> <angle>3.1415927410125732</angle>`

I don't understand how to do it, tried "if args<=0", but it doesn't give me a correct rotation, I assume that my solution is not the right way ...
Can someone help me in this situation ?

Thank you